# Custom cursors not shown in Safari

Tags: css, safari, cursor

I set the cursor as follow:

```css
cursor: url(https://my.server.com/resources/cursors/cursor_select.cur), crosshair;
```

It works on all browsers, except Safari.

What might be the solution?

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/suBmU/

Comment: It does not work with my cursor - are there any special limitation on the cursors that used in safari?

Comment: Not that I know about. Is it a valid cur file? It is hard to tell without seeing the actual file. The link above is invalid. Are there any errors in the console or the network inspector?